# How to check if program is on PATH before invoking it in gradle build script?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have the following function in my `build.gradle` script for Android Studio:

```
def getBuildCommit() {
    return ['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'].execute().text.trim()
}
```

This code fails with an error if `git` is not on `PATH`. My goal is that if `git` is not available, this should not fail but instead return a blank string and allow the build to continue normally. This code must function on both Windows and Linux host machines.

Is there a way I can first check if `git` is present (similar to `$ which git` on linux) prior to calling it? Or maybe a way to `execute()` without exceptions thrown in failure cases like this?

Comment: check if path variable contains what you are looking for

Comment: @Drako You mean like a substring search? That won't work as `git` won't exist in `PATH`. Also your recommendation is very primitive; I am hoping for a more built-in approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just wrap it in a try/catch block and return empty string if there was an exception.

But actually as you are in Gradle land, I'd use a task of Type `Exec` or the `exec` method anyway which both have the same capabilities. So in your case the full example would be something like

```
def getBuildCommit() {
    try {
        new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { out ->
            def result = exec {
                commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'
                ignoreExitValue true
                standardOutput out
                errorOutput = [ write: { Object... args -> } ] as OutputStream
            }
            return (result.exitValue == 0) ? (out as String).trim() : ''
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return ''
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems really overkill. What does that accomplish that the 1-liner I'm using doesn't? Honest question: I'm not familiar with Gradle, but at face value I do not see the benefit of all the extra code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want it as oneliner that has the same flaws as your original version, do `new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { out -> exec { commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'; standardOutput out }; return((out as String).trim()); }`. The extra lines do what you asked for. They use an empty string if the executable is not in the path, or if there is any other error like not being in a Git repository (build from a source zip e. g.). The Gradle version just is more flexible, powerfull and expressive in general. If you want original version to do what you want you need some additional lines too.